# A better workflow for a responsive web layout using DIV stacking

Tags: css, responsive-design, workflow

I had a requirement to put 2 image within a band on a page and then make it responsive to various screen sizes. So below a and b would represent these images and the band in red. The gap between a and b needed to remain proportional tho a and b were of slightly different width as A was a circular logo and b was a rectangular logo.

[image]

So I got it to work by moving through various screen size and manually adjusted the css according to what I saw using media queries as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
    <meta name="description" content="T">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
    <!-- Responsive and mobile friendly stuff -->
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style type="text/css">
    
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
    
html,body {
    color:#ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background: url('images/bg-1366.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
    background-size: cover;         /* Generic*/
}
#band{
    position: relative;
    top:27.5%;
    height:30%;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%; 
    border:3px solid #ffffff;
    border-right-style:none;
    border-left-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    align:center;
    padding:0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* For WebKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover;    /* Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover;      /* Opera*/
    background-size: cover;         /* Generic*/
}
#holistic {
    float:right;
    max-width: 80%; 
    max-height: 80%;
}

#spa {
    float:left;
    max-width: 90%; 
    max-height: 90%;
}
#off {
    float:left;
    max-width: 1%; 
    max-height: 1%;
}


    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/col.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/3acols.css" media="all">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css" media="all">
</head>    


<body>

    <div id="band">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="section group">
                <div class="col span_1_of_2">
                <img id="holistic" src="Ehlogo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col coloff span_3_of_2">
                <img id="off" src="images/off.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col span_1_of_2">

                <img id="spa" src="ESlogo.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

    @charset "utf-8";
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
     .col{
         text-align:center;
         }
        #holistic {
            float: none;
            max-width: 95%; 
            max-height: 95%;
        }
        #spa {
                float:right;
            max-width: 95%; 
            max-height: 95%;
            margin-top:7.5%;
            margin-right:10%;
        }
            #band {
            top:12.5%;
            height:30%; 
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) and (max-width : 640px) and (max-height : 960px){
     .col{
         text-align:center;
         width:640px;
            max-width: 100%; 
            max-height: 100%;
         }
        #holistic {
            float: none;
            max-width: 85%; 
            max-height: 85%;
        }
        #spa {
            float:right;
            max-width: 85%; 
            max-height: 85%;
            margin-top:7.5%;
            margin-right:10%;
        }
            #band {
            top:12.5%;
            height:30%; 
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) and (max-height : 800px){
     .col{
         text-align:center;
         }
        #holistic {
            float: none;
            max-width: 95%; 
            max-height: 95%;
        }
        #spa {
            float:none;
            max-width: 95%; 
            max-height: 95%;
            margin-right:10%;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 640px) and (max-width : 768px) and (max-height : 1280px){
     .col{
         text-align:center;
         width:768px;
            max-width: 100%; 
            max-height: 100%;
         }
        #holistic {
            float: none;
            max-width: 100%; 
            max-height: 100%;
        }
        #spa {
            float:none;
            max-width: 100%; 
            max-height: 100%;
            margin-top:3.5%;
            margin-right:3%;
        }
        #band {
            top:12.5%;
            height:25%; 
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    
        body{
            background: url('images/bg-1280.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        }
        #holistic {
            position:relative;
            top:-5px;
            left:10px;
            max-width: 90%; 
            max-height: 90%;
        
        }
        .coloff {
            width:75px;
        }
        #spa {
            float:right;
            margin-top:2%;
            margin-right:15%;
            max-width: 85%; 
            max-height: 85%;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1250px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (min-height: 1024px) {
    
        body{
            background: url('images/bg-1280.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        }
        #holistic {
            max-width: 90%; 
            max-height: 90%;
        
        }
        .coloff {
            width:75px;
        }
        #spa {
            float:right;
            margin-top:2%;
            margin-right:15%;
            max-width: 85%; 
            max-height: 85%;
        }
                #band {
            top:25%;
            height:32.5%;   
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 799px){
        body{
            background: url('images/bg-1366.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        }
        #holistic {
                position:relative;
            top:-16px;
            max-width: 100%; 
            max-height: 100%;
        }
        #spa {
            max-width: 90%; 
            max-height: 90%;
        }
            .coloff {
            width:165px;
        }
            #band {
            top:25%;
            height:32.5%;   
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1279px) and (max-height: 799px){
        body{
            background: url('images/bg-1366.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        }
        #holistic {
            max-width: 95%; 
            max-height: 90%;
        }
        #spa {
            float:left;
            max-width: 85%; 
            max-height: 85%;
        }
            .coloff {
            width:175px;
        }
        #band {
            top:25%;
            height:32.5%;   
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1580px) and (max-width: 1920px){
        body{
            background: url('images/bg-1366.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        }
        #holistic {
            max-width: 90%; 
            max-height: 90%;
        }
        #spa {
            float:left;
            max-width: 90%; 
            max-height: 90%;
        }
            .coloff {
            width:180px;
        }
        #band {
            top:25%;
            height:28.5%;   
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2400px){
        body{
            background: url('images/bg-1366.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        }
        #holistic {
            position:relative;
            top:-10px;
            max-width: 90%; 
            max-height: 90%;
        }
        #spa {
            margin-top:0.5%;
            float:left;
            max-width: 86%; 
            max-height: 86%;
        }
            .coloff {
            width:200px;
        }
        #band {
            top:25%;
            height:30%; 
        }
    }

/*  SECTIONS  ============================================================================= */

.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  GROUPING  ============================================================================= */


.group:before,
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.group:after {
    clear:both;
}
.group {
    zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

/*  GRID COLUMN SETUP   ==================================================================== */

.col {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; } /* all browsers except IE6 and lower */


/*  REMOVE MARGINS AS ALL GO FULL WIDTH AT 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .col { 
        margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
    }
}

/*  GRID OF TWO   ============================================================================= */


.span_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_2 {
    width: 10%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 40.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .span_2_of_2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .span_1_of_2 {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

My problem is that this was a total pain. It was a lot of guessing and entering % values / saving the file / reloading the browser to see how it looked / adjusting again and so on. Gah!

So I'm looking for a way to use math or a framework or some workflow algorithm to speed this up and take all the guess work out of it. My method was purely amateur hour but so far I cant find a better way to go at it when using percentages and media queries. This took me far too long.

Comment: try using firebug or similar to do real-time changes to your css

Comment: Im using dreamweaver on one screen and the browser on the other so i can edit-save-reload fairly quickly. Would firebug be an improvement on that? I'd still be guessing at the values wouldn't I? I'd like to find a way of calculating the values for such a "simple" layout without needing to resort to edit-save-reload. There must be some kind of math or design guidelines that allow computation of the various values upfront instead i stepped thru each of the screens and adjusted the media query values by sight. This would become exponentially more time consuming with just a couple more elements.

Comment: Sorry I thought the 'Gah!'  was specifically about saving / reloading the browser.  Firebug can allow you to make incremental changes and see the result real time - so useful for me.  If you have a lot of changes to make or do not know where to start, maybe there could be better.

Comment: Real time edits in Chrome as well, and easier, in my experience.  F12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go mobile first! There's a reason it's the mantra. It's so much easier to write your css to make it look good at the smaller screen size, then override for the larger size.

Start with your snap point fairly small, after you get your styling how you like it, resize your browser and let your eye decide where the snap point should be. Let the content dictate the style.

Comment: I think you might be right. Thinking about it I have scaled down rather than up and I can see how much easier a reverse in dev direction would make things. That's a great tip. Almost ridiculously obvious now that I think about it. Old habits ;(

Comment: I know... it seems so backwards. I struggle with it in every new design, however, it always seems to work well.